# Heroku - git repository branches destination

Tags: java, heroku

I create java app on heroku but I am a little bit confused about branches destination. I have master and HEAD branches. Which should be used for deployment? Can i delete HEAD and have only master?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HEAD` is a reference to the checked out commit and master is the usual name for your "default" branch. To deploy to heroku you have to deploy to Heroku's master branch, no matter from where:

Assuming a remote called `heroku` pointing to Heroku's git:

```
git push heroku master
git push heroku other_ref:master
```

The first line pushes your master, to heroku's master. You can specify a different branch like in the second line.

Comment: Hmm, i know what means checkout-switch between branches- but checkout commit? Ok, so master is my deployment branch and when i commit code it will be automatically deployed or i have to use heroku command ?

Comment: `checkout` simply changes your HEAD to said reference. Branch names, tag names, commits, HEAD they are all references. So `git checkout master` simply tells git to point HEAD to the commit identified by master. Committing simply adds the commit to your local git repository. For deploying, no heroku command is needed, just push your code to Heroku's master branch.